# Imgflip API lowercase

Tags: api, http

does anyone know with which parameter one can produce a lower case meme using the Imgflip API. On their official api docs I could not find anything but on the site you have the option for lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on request that their site makes when creating a picture, you should send the text as a property on an object within "boxes" array,

```
// form-data
{
  template_id: 12345,
  username: "username",
  password: "password",
  boxes[0][type]: "text",
  boxes[0][text]: "lowercase top string",
  boxes[0][force_caps]: 0,
  boxes[1][type]: "text",
  boxes[1][text]: "lowercase bottom string",
  boxes[1][force_caps]: 0,
}
```

"force_caps" is 0 by default, so you can omit it in this case.